# This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^14.0.0, but Angular version 15.0.1 was found instead

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, version

$ ng serve
This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^14.0.0,
but Angular version 15.0.1 was found instead.

Please visit the link below to find instructions on how to update Angular.
https://update.angular.io/

I am getting the above error, I tried downgrade, upgrade angular CLI versions, npm cache clean, open a new terminal, restart my laptop but nothing worked for me the error message persists.

The error message started appearing after installing the

```
@angular-builders/custom-webpack
```

My package.json given below.

```
{
  "name": "angular-amplify-cognito-updated",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1500.1",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^13.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.9",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.0.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^8.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: most likely have a wrong version of the pacakge. please post yout package.json or bare minimum the angular devDependancancies + builder

Comment: thanks for your response. I have updated the package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your package json you have angular 15, but based on their documentation you need to match their latest major version.
they only have beta for angular 15 for now ( 29/11/2022 )

so for now install the latest they have you can find the listed versions here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack?activeTab=versions

```
npm i -d @angular-builders/custom-webpack@15.0.0-beta.0
```

Link to their github telling you explicitly must match major version numbers: https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack#this-documentation-is-for-the-latest-major-version-only

Comment: thanks a lot, it helped me to get rid of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:
This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^13.0.0 || ^13.3.0-rc.0,
but Angular version 15.0.3 was found instead.

Please visit the link below to find instructions on how to update Angular.
https://update.angular.io/

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

loandigger
•
6mo ago
•
Edited 6mo ago
Install the node version manager, NVM.

npm install nvm

Then

NVM install node@6

NVM install node@8

NVM install node@10

NVM install node@12

NVM install node@14

NVM install node@16

NVM install node@18

So you have many different versions of node to work with. NVM will install the latest minor and point release for each major version.

NVM list

Will give you the major, minor and point releases for each major version. Then :

NVM use (version_here)

Like

NVM use 6.6.1

Use the lowest version number you installed to start.

Then

Ng serve

It will either work, or it will tell you the minimum version of node it needs to work. Then you 'NVM use #.#.#' to use whatever version is needed and NG serve again. Should at least compile.

Too bad there is no version manager for Angular.

P.s. Edit the angular.json file and remove the line at the bottom that says "defaultProject": ... That feature was removed from the angular spec a year or two ago.

P.p.s.

You also need multiple versions of Angular CLI running on your computer.

create a subdirectory in your repos directory called 'angular-11-repos'

Cd angular-11-repos

Npm install @angular/cli@11

Then clone the repo into this subdirectory and run the usual npm install, npm update, NG serve.